# Boot to Ubuntu if specific USB is inserted

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I have a Windows desktop machine that I share with my wife. I've been using Ubuntu for some time on my laptop but the motherboard died so I'm stuck with the desktop PC.

I'd like to dual boot the machine but with one condition. Only show the bootloader menu if a USB is inserted. If a USB is not inserted then it should boot into Windows.

I know it can happen since I read it some years ago but I can't seem to find the article. I imagine that I have to install grub to the USB drive?

How can I do this? Thanx for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to just set up your boot priorities in the BIOS. Set it to boot from a USB as the first option and then set your HDD with the Windows OS as the second option. That way when the computer is first turned on it will run through that sequence. If the USB is inserted it will go to that, if its not it will default to windows. You should install the os to the USB stick, like a 64gb stick per say, so you can save files and such on the drive.

Comment: Idea is good generally, but I would suggest to install only bootloader in the USB, not whole operating system. I'm not 100% sure if it is possible, but it's worth a try.

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-a-Linux-Operating-System-to-a-Flash-Drive-and-Install-Portable-Versions-of-Your-Favourite-Applications

Comment: I don't want to install the whole OS on my USB. Just the grub bootloader. I'll partition my main HDD into 2 partitions, an NTFS for Windows and an ext3/4 for Ubuntu. The thing is that I don't know how to separately install grub.

Comment: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/    this is a tutorial of how to set up a grub boot loader on a USB while using lunix. I'll look for a tutorial that u could do in windows because I assume that what the computer your on now is. Let me know if this is more along the lines of what you are looking for. I just tested it out and it seemed to work well.